# How to change debugger settings for debugging individual unit tests from VS 2015 Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging, uwp, .net-core

Test Explorer allows to run tests under debugger and I use it quite often for debugging single tests. However debugger settings used in this case are different from that set for the test project and prevent efficient debugging. I would like to limit debugging to managed mode only for UWP class library while debugger starts always in mixed native/managed mode. This prevents any debugging as .NET Core does not support mixed mode debugging. I work on VS 2015.

After checking and testing all possible settings I have failed to switch debugging mode from mixed to managed only. Any ideas?

**Not solved:** cleanup and rebuild of MEF cache resolved problem for a short time.

Debugging fails with error msg *Unable to attach to CoreCLR. Interop debugging is not supported*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The above problem is most probably **a bug** or **debugger/coreclr mismatch** in Windows runtime. With UWP runtime version 5.1.0 debugging in managed, native and mixed mode works perfectly. By updating UWP runtime version to 5.2.2 one can reproduce reported problem. By downgrading to UWP runtime 5.1.0 problem is resolved. Version of my VS is 2015 Update 3.1.

All the above problems were reproduced on clean Windows 10 Pro and VS 2015 Update 3.1 install.

**See comment 2 for workaround for UWP runtime v5.2.2**

Comment: if you make sure that it is related to the UWP runtime version, I suggest you use the old version as a workaround, and then report this issue to the Microsoft connect report team. Of course, you could also share a simple sample here, I will test it in my side, I will help you report it if I get the same issue as yours.

Comment: Pretty sure it is UWP v5.2.2 runtime problem.One can repro bug by throwing exception in the test which will crash UWP test app and after that will try to debug test i.e. memory access violation in finalizer called outside of test method. If runtime is updated from v1.0.3 which is used as default to v1.0.4 released with .NET Core 1.0.1 problems are fixed permanently even on v5.2.2 runtime. This is the workaround which I would recommend for time being. My understing is that bug was fixed in v1.0.4 of .NET Core runtime. We have to wait for next release of UWP runtime to get it "officially" fixed.

Comment: if so,  you could post the feedback here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx, so you could get latest information from the product team directly. Of course, since it works well in v1.0.4 of .NET core runtime, at least, it is a workaround now, you could mark your reply as a provisional answer before you get any information from connect report team. Have a nice day:)

Comment: I will do it. However, the crash of test framework Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformTest.* is indication of another bug -> test framework should not crash when finalizers are executed even if exceptions are thrown. Will report both to VS team.

Comment: Hi Jacek, I don't quite follow the workaround. I upgraded to UWP v5.2.2 from v.5.1.0 and experienced this problem. What are the steps need to resolve it in v5.2.2. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewJE Sorry for late reply but your message appeared today in my stackexchange inbox. The steps I have done it are as follows: 1. Upgrade to UWP 5.2.2, than upgrade from runtime v1.0.3 to v1.0.4 - the problem seems to be fixed in runtime v1.0.4 but not v1.0.3 which ships with UWP v5.2.2

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Jacek Blaszczynski's answer, I had to add Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR version 1.0.4 nuget package to make it work with Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform version 5.2.2. Interestingly, I was unable to use the current version 1.1.0. It would not even get installed.

As an alternative to MS Test I suggest using xUnit. It also works with UWP, does not require adding Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR nuget package and runs much faster. [Here](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-uwp.html) is a quick tutorial.

Comment: Confirm that 1.1.0 is no go for UWP v5.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Interop debugging is not supported means that you cannot debug both managed and native code types at the same time. For CoreCLR apps, use the attach to process and enable CoreClr, debug it again.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not solution to the problem itself. I am looking for debug settings which can be used to set up debugger for sessions started from Test Explorer. Obviously I could attach to test process but ...

Comment: Which developing language did your test project and previous project use? Do you enable or disable debugging options "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" and "Use Native Compatibility Mode" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging? For general C# app, if you want to debug native code, you could find the "Enable Native debugging" in the project property.

Comment: Problems arise with C# projects (both used in test and target projects). Both options "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" and "Use Native Compatibility Mode" are disabled (default settings), project settings (both) are set to Managed Debugging. However what I have noticed is that after solution configuration change i.e. from x86 to x64 debugging from Test Explorer is possible until tests throw some unhandled exceptions other then AssertException. The most damaging ones are coming from managed - native interop. This "enabling" trick is however unreliable.

Comment: @JacekBlaszczynski，If you want to debug an managed unit test in mix mode, we need to enable the "Enable native debugging". The UWP has his own test project template in VS IDE, but how you use the coreclr in your project? If you want to test the Coreclr project, the xunit will be a path, but it doesn't use the default UWP test project template. Or if there are different projects in the same solution, but they have to use different debugging option, create different solution would be a better workaround.