# UWP UnitTest debugging "Unable to attach to CoreCLR"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm having issues running Debug mode for unit tests in my UWP (Windows 10) project. The error thrown is:

`Unable to attach to CoreCLR. Interop debugging is not supported.`

The output from the test window shows:

```
Deployment complete (0:00:00,932). Full package name: "d13697af-b51e-4d46-bbce-4f4b89a44a95_1.0.0.0_x64__h20887da7bcmm"

A user callback threw an exception.  Check the exception stack and inner exception to determine the callback that failed.
```

The really weird thing is that this does not happen every time. I have successfully debugged my unit tests a couple of times now, until it fails. The remedy seems to be to clean the solution and rebuild, after which it sometimes (not always) works again for a few attempts. Then it starts failing and I need to clean again.

I'm building for Windows 10 build 10586, selecting another version doens't seem to make a different though.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am having the same issue. Seems to have stopped working since I added the SimpleStub package from Nuget?

Comment: Nope. The only package I have in my test project is .NET core at the moment, and it still fails from time to time. I also did a side install of VS "15" to see whether that would help, but it's probably SDK related as that also didn't make a difference.

Comment: Seems like we are not the only ones with this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399907/how-to-change-debugger-settings-for-debugging-individual-unit-tests-from-vs-2015 Seems it is an SDK issue.

Comment: You are definitely not the only ones with the issue. After reading your post, I tried cleaning and rebuilding my solution as well, which fixed it (temporarily) for me. This is strange.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had removed the "debugType": "portable", line from my project.json file.

"buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

Comment: This is not an answer, you should use `[Add comment]`